# In what direction does D.VA eject from her Mecha?

Tags: overwatch

I can't seem to ever predict where D.VA is going to go when she ejects from a dying Mechasuit. Is it player controlled, or is there a predetermined direction that she can go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She ejects out the back of it, so she's left standing directly behind where the mech died.  The reason you can't predict where she's going to go is that as soon as she's ejected out the back, she has a moment of invulnerability where she is free to move and dodge attacks.  This is to prevent players from immediately one shotting her as soon as she pops out the back of the mech.

Comment: And she has no control over which direction she goes? I distinctly remember there are times when she is to the left or right of her dead Mecha.

Comment: She does have control over where she goes.  Once she pops out the back, she has a moment of invulnerability and can start moving.  But if she didn't move, she would be directly behind the mech

Comment: Then the answer isn't exactly "standing directly behind where the mech died"...

Comment: Your question is "What direction does D.Va eject from" and I feel like I answered that.  If your real question is "Why can't I hit D.Va when she ejects" then you should edit the title

Comment: If you read the entire question, I go on to ask "is it player controlled", which you hadn't answered before your edit. Thanks.

Comment: The eject itself is not player controlled, but because she can start moving almost immediately after the eject it might look player controlled

Answer (score 6):

According to these two sites, [Icy Veins](http://www.icy-veins.com/overwatch/dva-strategy-gameplay-guide) and [Furious Paul](https://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/dva.html), players can control the direction of ejection by using the movement keys.  The default direction is backwards.

This matches with my own experiences.

Answer (score 3):

From [Furious Paul's D.Va Overwatch guide](https://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/dva.html):

> Steer D.va's Ejection
>
> When your mech gets destroyed, you can hold down the direction you want D.va to eject out at and she will jump out that direction.  This means you can hold your strafe, forward, and backward keys down while getting ejected and she will pop out that direction.  By default, if you don't press any movement keys, D.va will eject backwards away from her mech.

I play a lot of D.Va and can confirm that I try to eject in the direction that will put the mech in between me and enemies and/or get me closest to cover.